# algorithm to sort elements of three arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Here's the stumper:

> Start with three arrays A, B and C with a total of `2n+1` entries.
>   Write an algorithm to sort all of the entries from all of the arrays
>   using only the following two methods:
>
> 1. `X = sort(X)` replaces the array `X` with the sorted version.
> 2. `(X , Y) = doubleUp(X , Y)` does nothing if `X` has more elements
>      than `Y`, otherwise it removes the first `length(X)` entries from `Y`
>      and appends them to the end of `X`.

Here's what I've tried so far. If two of the arrays are empty, then just use `sort` on the nonempty array.

If one of the arrays is empty, then I think I can use `doubleUp` to get one array to have just one thing and the other array to have everything else, and if that singleton array has the smallest (or largest) element, then that works. So I can use `sort` after I use `doubleUp` each time to make sure this happens. I coded this up in Maple and it worked for all the cases I checked.

I have no idea how to do it with 3 arrays though. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This almost sounds like a homework problem..

Comment: Almost. I'm trying to prepare for interview-questions.

Comment: Could I ask you where this interview-question was asked? It seems a bit weird, or incomplete, or that'll have a strange solution that's not usefull anywhere else. I got curious

Comment: @woliveirajr: Sometimes such "stupid" question asked not to see if you know the answer or would find the solution, but to see how the candidate approaches the problem, how he thinks, and how he solves problems.

Comment: The problem statement doesn't say all the elements have to be in one array.  I think it would be valid to have `A[max] <= B[0] && B[max] <= C[0]`, and each array sorted individually.  Nobody's answered what I think is the straightforward interpretation of the question.  @SteveJessop's answer just shows that the weird interpretation makes it a pretty strange interview question, and concludes that the question isn't asking for all the elements in one array, without answering what to do otherwise.  I haven't yet thought of an answer to the question I think is being asked.

Comment: Are we allowed to do comparisons other than inside `sort()`?  e.g. to figure out which of A, B or C has the highest max element.  Or can we only look at A.size(), B.size(), C.size()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like nonsense. The total number of entries is odd. The only way to increase the length of an array is to make it the smaller first argument of `doubleUp`, in which case it ends up with an even number of elements. So unless all the elements are in one array to begin with there's no way to make one array contain all the elements, sorted or otherwise.

So, the desired final result is not a single array containing all the elements in order. Or if it is, then the answer to the question is "it cannot be done".

Comment: The OP never argued that all the elements end up in 1 array. Only that there is one singleton and the other contains `2n` elements. That he can do that isn't yet clear to me, but doesn't sound implausible.

Comment: @PengOne: I mean the quoted interview question sounds like nonsense. What does it mean for all the entries to be sorted, if they're not all in the same array? Either there's something in the question that I'm not seeing, or there's something missing from the question...

Comment: yeah, not sure about that. I'm still puzzling with his assertion when one array is empty.

Comment: @PengOne: I think I've stumbled over a counter-example: if the two non-empty arrays have initial sizes 3 and 1668, then repeatedly applying `doubleUp` (with the smallest first) returns to sizes 3, 1668 after 278 steps, without passing through 1, 1670. Since the sum of sizes is invariant, every starting pair must repeat within a number of steps equal to that sum, so it should be fairly easy to brute-force for the smallest counter-example even if there's no simple mathematical property that decides it...

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for the explanation. Sometime I don't understand the problems when they have a solution, but I guess this one I didn't understand for the right reason.

Comment: As the total entries is 2n+1(=3 when n=1). Take the case where A,B,C all have 1 element. doubleUP(1,1)=(2,0) and doubleUp(1,2) and doubleUp with any number with 0 produce the same number no this will not end in to any result.

Comment: @user430294: thanks, but I meant the smallest counter-example to Daniel's proposition, "If one of the arrays is empty, then I think I can use doubleUp to get one array to have just one thing and the other array to have everything else"

Comment: If the question is this incoherent and pointless, it's not a good test of programming, just a puzzle. I mean, this could be the most incoherent programming question I've ever seen. Whoever wrote that API should be shot, would be my answer (with proof of why the API doesn't do what it's intended to do).